# Use Rolles Theorem to show that the function $x^{n}+kx+l=0$ has at most 2 roots if $n$ is even?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

"Use Rolles Theorem to show that the function $x^{n}+kx+l=0$ has at most 2 roots if $n$ is even, and at most 3 roots if $n$ is odd?"

To do this, I assume I must show that there are certain values of $x$, given by some functions of $k$ and $l$ such that $f_{1}(k,l)<0, f_{2}(k,l)>0, f_{3}(k,l)<0$, but I'm unsure of how to proceed, or whether this is even the correct method.

Comment: Rolle's theorem says, that if you have $n$ zeros, you get $n-1$ stationary points. Show that in the even case you have at most $1$ stationary point, in the odd case at most $2$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you have written, I think you may be getting mixed up between Rolle's Theorem and the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Rolle's Theorem states ([Wikipedia version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle's_theorem)) that if a real-valued function $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a, b]$, differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$, and $f(a) = f(b)$, then there exists at least one $c$ in the open interval $(a, b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$.

Consider your function in the case of even $n$.  If it has three roots $x_1<x_2<x_3$, then $f'(x)$ is zero at least twice - once in the interval $(x_1,x_2)$, again in the interval $(x_2,x_3)$.  Can you show that this is impossible and hence finish the problem?

Good luck!

Comment: Of course! I am getting the 2 theorems confused. Apologies for such a stupid mistake, and thanks for the answer.